# How to compute the force on a mass traveling along a parametric curve?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

Suppose a mass (m) is traveling along a parametric curve {x(t), y(t)} where x(t), y(t) are twice differentiable. What is the centrifugal fore on the mass as a function of time?

I am an engineer, and I learned about centrifugal force of a mass in uniform circular motion in college physics. I also know the osculating radius is the reciprocal of curvature given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curvature.html). That is a good start, but there are details I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a fixed path here is how to find the relevant kinematic quantities

$$ \begin{array}{r|l}
\text{quantity} & \text{expression}\\
\hline \text{position} & \boldsymbol{r}(s)=\begin{pmatrix}x(s)\\
y(s)
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{tangent vector} & {\bf e}=\frac{\boldsymbol{r}'}{\|\boldsymbol{r}'\|}\\
\text{velocity} & \boldsymbol{v}={\bf e}\,v\\
\text{normal vector} & {\bf n}=\begin{pmatrix}-e_{y}\\
e_{x}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{acceleration} & \boldsymbol{a}={\bf e}\,\dot{v}+{\bf n}\,\frac{v^{2}}{\rho}
\end{array} $$

where $v$ is the speed, and $\rho$ is the radius of curvature (it can be positive or negative depending if the normal vector $\bf n$ points towards the center of turn or away.

The force $\boldsymbol{F} = m \boldsymbol{a}$ can decomposed into tangential and perpendicular components as

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \boldsymbol{F}_\parallel &= {\bf e} (m \dot{v}) \\
 \boldsymbol{F}_\perp & = {\bf n} ( \tfrac{m v^2}{\rho} )
\end{aligned}$$

Also, note that in 2D

the tangent vector is $$ {\bf e} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}} \pmatrix{x' \\ y' } $$

and the curvature is

$$ \boxed{ \frac{1}{\rho} = \frac{ x' y'' - x'' y'}{ \left( x'^2 + y'^2 \right)^{1.5} } } $$

where the apostrophe $'$ denotes derivative with respect to the path parameter $s$

---